# backspace text field flutter on ios not working

Tags: ios, flutter, backspace

I have a textfield to fill the cellphone number,
I use the controller for the textfield, but when I change the page to the OTP page and return to the cellphone number page, the delete / backspace button on IOS doesn't work, and when I try to re-enter the cellphone number, the cellphone number that was previously lost,

for example my cellphone number before going to the otp page is 085735208000, and when I return to the cellphone number page this number 085735208000 still appears, but when I type again, the number 085735208000 is missing

please help :(

here my code

```
class InputMdnWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const InputMdnWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _InputMdnWidgetState createState() => _InputMdnWidgetState();
}

class _InputMdnWidgetState extends State<InputMdnWidget> {
  var _controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<LoginRegisterBloc, LoginRegisterState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return ContainerDefault(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.h, left: 5.w, right: 5.w),
          child: 
          TextField(
            controller: _controller,
            onChanged: (mdn) {
              context.read<LoginRegisterBloc>().add(MdnChanged(mdn));
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a temporary solution which is we can unfocus the Textfield after pop from OTP verifying screen to prevent this issue.

```
void _submitForm() async {
_isSubmitted = true;
_setIsLoading(true);
if (_validateForm()) {
  try {
    // Some logic code
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/auth/verify_phone_step',
        arguments: {'phoneNumber': _phoneNumberController.text});
  } finally {
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
  }
}
_setIsLoading(false);
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Thanks for helping so far. It would be great if you give some code example though. Please do so.

Comment: @AndyA. I just add my sample code to the answer. It worked for me.